# How do i figure out how much thrust an 150cc Size Brushless Outrunner Motor will output with propellers?

Tags: mobile-robot, quadcopter, motor, research

I need to know this as i'm trying to figure out if two of these could lift approximately 170 pounds of wheight. And that's includig batterys and the motors.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics:SE. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The way to know that is mostly to test, usually with a regulated power (not a battery) and with a scale. Those measurements are available for a variety of motor/propeller pairs on-line, they are usually provided by re-sellers.

If you use those be careful about the propeller pitch do not focus only on its diameter, as the pitch  as important aerodynamics effects.
Also watch out the voltage at which the test are conducted, typically in flight with battery you have a varying voltage and you might need to take some safety margin to compensate that.